# Does negative zero exist?

Tags: arithmetic, definition, real-numbers

In the set of real numbers, there is no negative zero. However, can you please verify if and why this is so? Is zero inherently "neutral"?

Comment: Is there positive zero? Not directly related, but it might be interesting to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)

Comment: I thought it was more an issue that $+0 = -0 = 0$ rather than $+0$ and $-0$ not existing.

Comment: Yes, with IEEE floating point numbers, but that's a matter for sci comp stackexchange.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: If you're rounding up from a negative number, you can get a negative 0.

Answer (score 25):

There is a negative $0$, it just happens to be equal to the normal zero. For each real number $a$, we have a number $-a$ such that $a + (-a)=0$. So for $0$, we have $0+(-0)=0$. However, $0$ also has the property that $0+b=b$ for any $b$. So $-0=0$ be canceling the $0$ on the left hand side.

Comment: -1. Zero is neither positive nor negative. The definition of positive (resp. negative) is that $a>0$ ($a<0$), and it's obvious that $0$ satisfies neither.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD you are rigth.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD When the answer says "negative zero," it is referring to the inverse of zero under addition, not literally a zero that is negative.

Answer (score 2):

A common definition of negative is "less than zero". In this sense, zero isn't negative (nor positive for a similar reason).

But the opposite of zero is well defined: it is zero. The unary $+$ or $-$ operators can very well be applied to $0$, with no effect.

One can admit that zero has no sign. The $\text{sign}$ function is usually defined to be $-1,0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

My thought on the problem is that all numbers can be substituted for variables. -1 = -x. "-x" is negative one times "x". My thinking is that negative 1 is negative 1 times 1. So in conclusion, I pulled that negative zero (can be expressed by "-a") is negative 1 times 0, or just 0 (-a = -1 * a).